# Formatting an Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm pulling an array from the database and it looks like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tracker_id] => 28
            [tracking_numbers] => hdkshwuy47937892hd
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tracker_id] => 28
            [tracking_numbers] => 797825464411
        )

)
```

I need to reformat it to look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tracker_id] => 28
            [tracking_numbers] => Array
                (
                   [0] => hdkshwuy47937892hd
                   [1] => 797825464411
                )
        )

)
```

I can't seem find the right search in the array or keys to create an array of numbers for the single tracker id.

Answer (score 2):

Use [array_column()](https://www.php.net/array_column) for < php V5.5

```
 <?php
    $a=array
    ( array
        ('tracker_id' => 28,
                'tracking_numbers'=> "hdkshwuy47937892hd"
            ),
    
        array('tracker_id' => 28,
                'tracking_numbers' => "797825464411",
            ) );
    
     $a[0]['tracking_numbers']=array_column($a,"tracking_numbers");
    unset($a[1]);
    print_r($a);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://eval.in/98539)</kbd>

Comment: Sadly the server my client is on is not 5.5

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$arr_output = array();
foreach($arr_input as $arr)
{
    $tracker_id = $arr['tracker_id'];
    $tracking_numbers = $arr['tracking_numbers'];

    $arr_output[$traker_id][] = $tracking_numbers;
}

print_r($arr_output);
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
$arr_output = array();
$arr_output1 = array();
foreach($arr_input as $arr)
{
    $tracker_id = $arr['tracker_id'];
    $tracking_numbers = $arr['tracking_numbers'];

    $arr_output[$traker_id][] = $tracking_numbers;
}
$i=0;
foreach($arr_output as $key=>$value)
{
    $arr_output1[$i]['tracker_id']=$key
    $arr_output1[$i]['tracking_numbers']=$value
    $i+=1;
}

print_r($arr_output1);
```

Comment: Almost.  But this sets the array key to the tracker_id and that's not quite right. Let me try your update.